# Vim -- Contextually changing behavior of a command based on syntax

Tags: vim

I tend to have comment lines like this:

```
// This is a comment. 
// This is the second line of a comment paragraph.

// This is a second paragraph...
```

I have my cursor in the middle of these lines and I want to start adding something. Often it is adding a sentence at the beginning of a paragraph. Hitting `I` will take me to before `//`. This is something I want to do often enough that it slightly bugs me that there isn't a quick way to get there without a bunch of movement commands or awkward reaches like `^wi`.

I want to adjust the `I` command to be "smart", so that only if my cursor is in a comment syntax area do I want vim to execute `^wi`.

Can I do this? I am pretty sure I can do this because I have a little command somewhere that is capable of telling me the syntax type that the cursor is inside of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it as a one-liner, but when conditionals are involved, I prefer to use a function:

```
:nnoremap I :call SmartInsert()<CR>
```

In the function, you can use `synIDattr()` to get the name of the active syntax item; see the example under `:help synID()`.  Then you can take different actions depending on whether the name contains "Comment".  Move the cursor as desired, then end the function with `:startinsert`.

```
:help synIDattr()
:help =~?
:help :if
:help :startinsert
:help user-functions
```

**Edit by OP:** Thanks for this great starting point. I got around to writing the function, here it is. It's real handy.

```
function! SmartInsert()
    if synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name") =~ "LineComment$"
        normal! ^w    " Can enhance this with something more general (no need tho)
        startinsert
    else
        call feedkeys('I', 'n')
    endif
endfun

nnoremap I :call SmartInsert()<CR>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this screws with `.` repeat command functionality. It used to be if I was commenting a line I would type `I// `, then subsequently move around and hit `.` on a bunch more lines to comment them all. But now this will not work because the repeat will only repeat an insertion (at least it knows to remember that much...) but the `^` is clearly not stored for it. I am now experimenting with `feedkeys()`...

Comment: in practice we almost never actually need to dot-repeat here. Also, for a modern approach I've adjusted the syntax check with `require'nvim-treesitter-playground.hl-info'.get_treesitter_hl()` and looking for comment inside. Since treesitter clobbers the traditional vim syntax system.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a mapping like this to move your cursor to first word after `/`

```
nmap <leader>I F/wi
```

Here's a small demo:

[image: demo gif]
<sub>(source: [gfycat.com](https://zippy.gfycat.com/MiserableEnchantedDormouse.gif))</sub>

Comment: Oh actually you know what, that logic might be enough. Though, sometimes comments start with `#`, or `*` (multiline). That was the reason for `^wi`.

Comment: But `^wi` would fail on lines such as 2 and 4 in the example where you have repeated `//`

Comment: Your example. Not mine.

Comment: You are right. Not sure how I got those repeated. Then you can map `I`  to `^wi`

Answer (score 0):

As I hinted in the comment to the accepted answer, this is the lua/treesitter solution!

```lua
    -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/22282505/340947
    local is_comment_ts_hl = function()
      local hl = require'nvim-treesitter-playground.hl-info'.get_treesitter_hl()
      -- loop
      for _, v in ipairs(hl) do
        -- if any contain 'comment': typical values seen are: { "* **@error**", "* **@comment**", "* **@spell**", "* **@spell**" }
        if string.find(v, 'comment') then
          return true
        end
      end
      return false
    end
    
    _G.smart_insert_start_of_line = function()
      if is_comment_ts_hl() then
        vim.cmd[[normal! ^w]]
        vim.cmd[[startinsert]]
      else
        vim.api.nvim_feedkeys('I', 'n', true)
      end
    end
    
    vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'I', ':lua smart_insert_start_of_line()<CR>', {noremap = true, silent = true})
```